# How can I add padding to the Colorbox modal window?

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

Is it possible to add padding to a Colorbox modal window? I would like some space in between the modal window edges and the content. I tried the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` property but I don't see any difference.

```
// Display inline content in Colorbox window
$(".inline").colorbox({
    inline: true, 
    fixed: true,
    height: "80%",
    width: "80%",
    innerWidth: "50%",
    innerHeight: "50%"
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know this is not possible to be done. You need to set the padding of loaded content. For example if your inline content is `#content you` can simply do:

```
<div id="content" style="padding: 20px;">bla bla bla</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Blonde moment – I should have thought of that :P

Answer (score 3):

To add a padding to the modal window i wouldn't style it via the jQuery settings nor within the html. I would recommend doing it by altering the user style part within the provided CSS file. e.g. add a padding to the #colorbox selector or add a margin to the #cboxContent selector.